# how to determine a matrix is satisfied with cancellation property in discrete mathematics.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Please forgive my bad English,I am confused about the cancellation property.Here are three examples on my textbook.Are they satisfied cancellation property?

(1)

- a b c

a a b c

b b c a

c c a b

(2)

^ a b c

a a b c

b b b b

c c b c

(3)

÷ a b c

a a b c

b a b c

c a b c

Can anyone explain it to me?The definition on my textbook really confused me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming in each case you're giving us the Cayley table of an operation on a three-element set $\{a, b, c\}$.  Thus in your first example $a \cdot a = a,\; a \cdot b = b, \ldots, c \cdot c = b$.

In the first example, each row and column contains $a$, $b$ or $c$ only once, so you do have cancellation.  However, in the second, the second row and second columns are all $b$'s.  Do you see how that tells you cancellation does not hold, either on the left or on the right?  Similarly, in the third example, the columns are constant.  What does that tell you?

Comment: Thank you for answering my quwstion.I have understood.